# How long does it take for the google disavow to remove links?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

For almost few years, My website used to rank for a certain keywords. In last 2 months, My keyword is going away from first page.

When I analysed the Google web master, came to know about too many bad back links from around 350 domains. (IMO) Those domains are specifically created to build a backlink to my website.

Now, I have uploaded a txt file in google disavow. How long will it take to process by Google ?

Comment: To know in detail, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/T0ryYFuLw64

Comment: The not so fun answer is: 10 days - 6 months. There are so many factors that affect the speed. I would keep an eye on the keyword ranking every week along with the organic visitor traffic to the affected page(s).

Comment: This question should not be marked as a duplicate. In another question, there is no sufficient information/answer. Keep this question open, will get more quality answer.